# Meaning of "run" in "run you around 700 dollars!"

Tags: verbs, definition

I was watching a YouTube clip (the AVGN 3DO episode) and heard this usage of "run".

> The complete copy can run you around 700 dollars today!

There should be a definition of "run" that matches this usage, but I couldn't find it. Is there any definition similar to "cost"?

Comment: Could it have been "can run to around 700 dollars"? That is the usual phrasing. If you link to the youtube video, someone might check.

Comment: @JamesK To my American ears, *run you around 700 dollars* is completely idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this use, it means *cost* (the verb):

[Merriam-Webster *run*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run)

> 12 b verb: cost (sense 1)
> *rooms that run $50 a night*

[Merriam-Webster *cost*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cost)

> 1 verb: to require expenditure or payment
> *rooms that run $50 a night*

(The M-W example is the same for both entries.)

A quick check shows that American Heritage Dictionary and Collins also show that sense. It may be hard to find the applicable sense because *run* is a common word that is very "overloaded", that is, it has many specific senses that don't have much to do with the pedestrian one.